# Computer crash while installing sdk emulators 8.1 windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

I tried many times to install windows phone sdk emulators 8.1, and it starts normally and at the end of installation my PC crashes. After I push the reset button the visual studio installation starts again and again my pc crashes....
I tried different links to download happens the same thing.
I tried to install the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and when starts to install the emulators the pc crashes again.

I have AMD FX 8350 8-core -64bit (4.2 GHz)
RAM 8 GB
Graphic Card AMD HD 6570 (latest drivers install)
OS Windows 8.1 Pro
I have installed the Visual Studio Express 2013.

Is this a problem from my pc specifications?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so there is a problem in your pc specification,but I will suggest you download web installer from dev.windowsphone.com and install the software,if it still crashes contact visual studio support.